# How to run Clockwork in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, background-task, clockwork

I'm really new to Heroku, but I have a problem. I have created a `Clockwork` script called "clock.rb" in rails and I use:

```
bundle exec clockwork clock.rb
```

to run it in the background on my local server, but How I can run that on Heroku server? (I would like the cheapest solution)

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To your `Procfile` use like this

```
worker: bundle exec clockwork clock.rb
```

it will start the server every time after Heroku push/web server restart.

Or you can run using `console` from your computer like this but in this case, you need to run every time after web server restarting

```
heroku run bundle exec clockwork clock.rb
```

and from Heroku open `console` and type

```
bundle exec clockwork clock.rb
```